# ChartBoost Interstitial banner not show in Android Studio Application

Tags: android, ads, interstitial, chartboost

I am working with an android app using `Android Studio`. i am using `ChartBoost` interstitial banner in my android app.
I have use `ChartBoost` `Android SDK` integration link for my code to integrate ChartBoost SDK;
I have properly follow the chartboost link & place the appId & appsignature  in `strings.xml`.   Here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
import com.chartboost.sdk.CBLocation;
import com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost;
import com.chartboost.sdk.ChartboostDelegate;
import com.chartboost.sdk.Libraries.CBLogging;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd, mInterstitialAd1;

    private static final String TAG = "Chartboost";
    // This is the object for Startapp Ads Banner
    private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //This is the AppID for Startup Ads Banner
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "xxxxxxxxx", false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, getResources().getString(R.string.appId), getResources().getString(R.string.appSignature));
        Chartboost.setLoggingLevel(CBLogging.Level.ALL);
        Chartboost.setDelegate(delegate);
        Chartboost.onCreate(this);


        if ( Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT) ) {
            Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
        }


        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.inter_ad_unit_id));
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial();

        mInterstitialAd1 = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd1.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.inter_ad_unit_id));
        mInterstitialAd1.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial1();
            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial1();

        startAppAd.loadAd(new AdEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
            }
        });


        Button shareIt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareIt);
        shareIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareIt();
            }
        });


    }

    //-------------- Shareit Button ---------------//
    private void shareIt() {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Business and Visiting Cards Maker");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ata.business.visiting.cards.maker");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }

    public void click_card(View v) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private ChartboostDelegate delegate = new ChartboostDelegate() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRequestInterstitial(String location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SHOULD REQUEST INTERSTITIAL '" + (location != null ? location : "null"));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldDisplayInterstitial(String location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SHOULD DISPLAY INTERSTITIAL '" + (location != null ? location : "null"));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void didCacheInterstitial(String location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "DID CACHE INTERSTITIAL '" + (location != null ? location : "null"));
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Chartboost.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Chartboost.onResume(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Chartboost.onPause(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Chartboost.onStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Chartboost.onDestroy(this);
    }


    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial1() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd1.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK):
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExitPanel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                startAppAd.showAd();
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In Android Studio Logcat Interstitial Banner is load but in my Android device Interstitial banner is not shows.
And in ChartBoost Dashboard Interstitial banner is in Portrait Form.
CTR, Impressions & downloads are showing.
But the issues is that Interstitial Banner is not showing in MainActivity.java

Can anyone tell me what location should i have use & what is the problem why Interstitial Banner is not showing in my Android device or in Emulator?
And i have also tried the Hotspot Sheild VPN ... But it useless?

Comment: Hey there, Chartboost support would be happy to help if you wrote into the support line at support@chartboost.com. Once we have resolved the answer there, I'd be happy to come back here and post the tl;dr version of the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT) ) {
            Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
  } else {
      Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
 }
```

This is only the part of your Interstitial Ad from Chartboost. What are you doing, when your Activity starts it checks Chartboost having any Interstitial Ad of Location **CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT** then it returns false because you haven't requested any such Ad.  Then by else part you request an Interstitial Ad for **CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT** location.

After a while, may be you have an Interstitial Ad, then when you check the value of `Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT)` return true and 
`Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);` show you Ad.

Use Delegate's method that tell you, your Ad is ready for display.